# Google Books api not giving output

Tags: android, json, google-books

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9789382563792
```

I have used this query from both mobile and browser and the response is -

```
{
  "kind": "books#volumes",
  "totalItems": 0
}
```

but when i use some other isbn like-

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9788172234980
```

this gives the response of the book.

When i remove the isbn from the query then it gives a lot of result which is not relevant.

So how do i use google books api to always get result from the google books.

I have also used this by appending api-key and then also it doesn't work.

I have tried a lot of ISBN numbers but only few of them are working and others give the same output of totalItems : 0 in response.

This books are famous books and should be found by google books is giving either irrelevant result or no result.

I want this to integrate to my android app with barcode scanner, so that user can see the books details and save it in application.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the isbn works well with the google api books, in others no. It is a severe bug from Google. 
Certain cases this doesn't work :

`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:`

and this works well:

`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=ISBN:`

To retrieve more information about this bug you can read this [discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/books-api/7Vlv3qc1F08) but the solution is null.

Answer (score 1):

So it's better to use GoodReads API as it gives you the results by popularity factor. But for google books API try using query without ISBN but it might give some unwanted results,
 `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=` 
 Just put isbn number after `q` no need to write the word `isbn:` or `ISBN:`. Again it might show some unwanted results see this link here 
 [Google Books API - Book Details not Returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410353/google-books-api-book-details-not-returned?rq=1)